# Wildfly 8.x ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.virtual.VFS

Tags: spring, jboss, wildfly, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to deploy an `ear` application on a wildfly 8.x server.

The problem is when I want to start my server, the log console printed me the following errors:

```
    14:00:09,825 ERROR [org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss VFS packages (for both JBoss AS 5 and 6) were not found - JBoss VFS support disabled
    14:00:09,835 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans/gardian_beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at 
   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver$VfsResourceMatchingDelegate.findMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:652) [spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
            ... 24 more
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect JBoss VFS packages
            at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.<clinit>(VfsUtils.java:109) [spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
            ... 39 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.virtual.VFS from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @67117f44 (finder: local module finder @5d3411d (roots: /abb/assetsuite/wildfly-8.2.1.Final.as/modules,/abb/assetsuite/wildfly-8.2.1.Final.as/modules/system/layers/base))]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.springframework.core.io.VfsUtils.<clinit>(VfsUtils.java:99) [spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
            ... 39 more
```

My JBoss does not recognize `org.jboss.virtual.VFS` class.

Here is my `module.xml` for my module `org.springframework.spring.main` :

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.springframework.spring">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <!--<resource-root path="groovy-all-2.3.4.jar"/>-->
        <resource-root path="spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-beans-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-expression-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-jms-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Of course, I have all jar referenced in the same folder as my `module.xml`..

Comment: It looks like you need a dependency on org.jboss.vfs in it.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a dependency on org.jboss.vfs in it.

You can fix this by

If you have the spring jars under your applications WEB-INF\lib folder then add the following dependency to your "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" file
Or if you are using spring as a separate module then you have to add this as the a dependency to your module.xml in your spring module.

```
<module name="org.jboss.vfs"></module>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Resolved by adding that in my `module.xml` inside `<dependencies>`:

```
<module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
```

Don't forget to check if you have the library inside the `org.jboss.vfs folder`.